# Send a prop to a child component

Tags: reactjs, function, parent-child, react-props

I am trying to change one `component` of a `child component` when another child component makes some action.

I have a parent class here:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={visible:true};
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child1 handleClick={this.handleClick} />
        <Child2 visible={this.state.visible} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child1 extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.handleClick();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>//some codes</div>;
  }
}
```

The function `handleClick` from the parent function works once.

Then it keeps giving me the **error** saying `_this.props.handleClick` is not a function. And there are no props from the second time.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to pass parent's handleClick to child1, then update the state via a button, then show this state in Child2? If so, you are not using passed handleClick in Child1. Also, you don't have any state in your parent component?

Comment: My bad, you are using the passed one and it seems working here.

Comment: i have updated the question. the function handleClick works fine on the first try. Why doesn't it work after that? It keeps giving me the error

Comment: I've used your code and it works here: https://codesandbox.io/s/9z4542qzkw

Comment: your code works just fine https://codesandbox.io/s/xpj3w193vp may be some other code might be causing problems

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it works :

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child1 handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      { this.state.visible && <Child2 />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

For reference : https://codesandbox.io/s/5zl8q7l744

Hope it helps.

Comment: it does not toggle the first time becase visible is not handle in the Child2 component. 
checking on the parent state and render child2 if the state changes did the trick